# How to retrieve Data from an external function in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, next.js

I'm using an embed form (paperform) on my website, and I need to get some form data after submission.

After the submission, the user stays on the same page of my website and a success message is displayed, then a function let's call it myGlobalFunction, is called through paperform. It is passed a single argument which is an object containing my data.

This works in a Vanilla JS project and returns the object

```
function myGlobalFunction(data){
    console.log(data)
}
```

How do I get to retrieve that data in NextJS?

Thanks!

Comment: https://paperform.co/help/articles/how-can-i-embed-my-form-in-a-react-app/